# why use a dll instead of a class

Tags: c#, .net

i joined a new project where they use c#.
I noticed that several dll's were being add in the references

From my knowledge and the e-learning that i have done, after building a class(which has some Methods & data), a DLL is generated.

Now in a new project, the class that just got converted into a DLL is added as a reference so that the functions defined in it could be called.

So, now my question is:
1) what is the need for converting the class file into a DLL file. Even it were a Class file, I could still be calling the functions defined in it by adding its namespace at the top of the code

2) If After adding the reference of the DLL , I deleted the entire contents of the project, leaving only the dll untouched(and in the same place), would the class using this dll still work

Answer (score 9):

Separating your code into different projects (each of which will create a separate assembly) has various benefits:

- It makes the structure of your code clear. For example, it can separate your storage layer from your business logic, and also from your user interface.
- It allows reuse: two different user interfaces can refer to the same assembly containing the business logic, for example.
- It allows greater encapsulation: classes which are *only* needed within their own assemblies can be declared as `internal` (which is the default for top-level classes in C# anyway) which means code in other assemblies won't even know about them. If all your code is in a single assembly, all those classes will "know about" each other.

Now choosing just how many projects to have is a balancing act - I've certainly seen applications where this has gone *much* too far, with lots of assemblies containing just a single class. If you have a large number of assemblies, that becomes a headache in terms of project and reference management. However, having too *few* assemblies makes it harder to reuse that code cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Jon Skeets answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21349157/238902), I'd like to add "updateability" as well. For me, this has two benefits

- one is that the build time becomes smaller if only one project needs to be rebuilt
- and second, pushing to "release" could be limited to a few dlls instead of one major .exe.

The first might not be a big deal in C# since projects build pretty fast, but for instance switching to C++ would be a big impact, since C++ code take a long time to compile.

Answer (score 0):

The benefit of Separating is that it lets you change the internal implementation without breaking client code. It doesn't protect you if you decide that you need to change the interface to your code, but that's a different matter.

they can reuse their code. but if they use classes every time they need to implement these classes ( in the best way copy and paste all codes )

when they use dlls in instead of classes they can update all project easily by just Update one or more dll although if you use class in multiple projects you suould modify all classes in all projects.

Answer (score 0):

I might add that a class is a language construct while an assembly is a deployment package.
Already in UML those are two totally different things.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_(UML)

When approaching the new idea of subdividing a solution, projects may be seen as "places" in which to put namespaces (i.e. folders) and classes (i.e. files).

It will take some time until you realize that a project best fits the concept of stratum (or layer) which is an architectural separation of a system.

When stratifying a system, you'll realize that the most crucial problem to tackle are the dependencies between strata (which would be the references to projects or dlls).

There cannot be loops but more important, you should study OCP (Open-Closed principle) and ISP (Interface Segregation Principle) and DIP (Dependency Inversion Principle) of SOLID:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)

At that point a new question will emerge. How can you know which classes depend on each other or do not? You may draw class diagrams, but there is a conceptual approach to the problem. Over the years it becomes a "practice" of designing systems. The concepts are described for educational purposes in GRASP:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)

The most important parts of GRASP for stratification are "Low Coupling" and "High Cohesion". In other words, you should batch functionally very similar classes in a stratum and separate through the stratification classes that functionally are not very much related to each other.